# Как правильно составить условие проверки валидности?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

```
<body>
    <form action="BD.php" method="POST">
        <p>Логин:</p><input type="text" name="login">
        <p>Пароль:</p><input type="password" name="password">
    </form>
<div id="error" style="display: none;"><p>Ошибка логина или пароля!</p></div>
<div id="okno-cap" style="display: none;"><input type="text" name="kod"></div>
</body>
```

Есть такой код. Как можно реализовать такое:
При вводе логина и пароля, они проверяются в БД. Ответ из БД будет получатся в переменную $check; Ответ может содержать 2 значения: значение 1 (правильные данные) и значение 0 (ошибка).
И так, эти ответы я получаю на PHP и конечно же как их перевести в JS я знаю:

```
var logpass = "<?echo $check;?>";
```

Так вот как теперь мне сделать так, чтобы при **значении 1 в переменной logpass**, стиль div-а с идентификатором **okno-cap** менялся **display:none;** на **position: fixed; z-index: 1000; max-width: 1419px; left: 466px; top: 21px;** и так же при **значении 0 в переменной logpass**, div-а с идентификатором **error** менялся **display:none;** на **color: rgb(204, 51, 0);**.

Дополнительный вопрос:
У меня получается 2 файла index.php с кодом HTML выше и немного с кодом JS. и файл BD.php где обработчик формы. Понимаете ли, как то я не правильно делаю структуру, так как такое вроде делается без перезагрузки страницы. То есть мне как то надо сделать, чтоб данные отправлялись в BD.php, и возвращали ответ уже в JS переменную без перезагрузки страницы. Я так думаю это надо Ajax наверно. Если можно, подскажите как это сделать правильно. Буду искренне благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

```
var logpass = "<?echo $check;?>";
if(logpass == 1)
{
$("#error").hide();
$("#okno-cap").show();
}
else
{
$("#error").show();
$("#okno-cap").hide();
}
```

нуба кодинг но как идея

Comment: а что за show() и hide()?)